Binding to a DeviceAdminService and calling its methods
I have a device admin app that is the device owner and I want to bind to the DeviceAdminService class that the admin app has from another app.
The problem is that the DeviceAdminService class has onBind set to final so I cannot override it like you can with normal service to set my service class as the binder to be able to call the methods of my service class from another app.
How can I bind to this service class in another app so I can call my service methods when I cannot override the onBind?

That kind of goes contrary to the entire security policy.  A device admin owner owns the device and can control anything on it.  THere's no security to what apps can bind ot a service.  So if apps are allowed to bind to a device admin service, then the admin service is completely compromised.

Fair point for sure

DevicePolicyManager class has a method called bindDeviceAdminServiceAsUser. it allows secondary user to bind to device admin service. But how to get instance of the service inside onServiceConnected callback I have no idea.
